# How to determine the owner of an embedded Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

I would like to change ownership of a shared Google Calendar that is embedded on our website, however nobody knows who owns the Calendar.

How can we determine the owner knowing just the HTML embed code?

Comment: I guess nobody knows this?  I have the same problem.

Comment: I can't even figure out who owns the calendar that is shared to me in my "Other Calendars" list.  There's no way to tell at all.  You can see who made entries, but not who owns the calendar.  I need to export this calendar but can't find the owner.